# Tratar evento backbutton em APP PWA criado no Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic

Li que para PWA criado no Ionic não tem a solução para tratar quando o usuário clicar o backbutton, botão fisíco.
O problema é quando o usuário clicar múltiplas vezes no backbutton até retornar a página de login. Quero verificar se ela está na última página antes da página de login e perguntar se ele quer sair da aplicação.

Alguém pode compartilhar alguma solução aplicada?

Executei alguns testes e não tive sucesso.
O código abaixo foi executado logo na primeira página após o login.

```
constructor(
    public _Platform: Platform,
  ) {  
 this._Platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(10000, () => {
      alert('ok');
    });  
}
```

Tentei também no app.component.ts

```
initializeApp() {
    this._Platform.ready().then(() => {
      this._StatusBar.styleDefault();
      this._SplashScreen.hide();
    });

    this._Platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(10000, () => {
      alert('OK');
    });    
  }
```

Em todos os casos não retorna o alert.

Answer (score 0):

Conforme a documentação: https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/hardware-back-button#exiting-the-app

Para Angular seria (estou usando capacitor, mas pode usar com cordova também):

```
import { IonRouterOutlet, Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { App } = Plugins;

constructor(
  private platform: Platform,
  private routerOutlet: IonRouterOutlet
) {
  this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(-1, () => {
    if (!this.routerOutlet.canGoBack()) {
      //Chame a mensagem de confirmação customizada aqui, se confirmar execute App.exitApp();
    }
  });
}
```

React:

```
import { useIonRouter } from '@ionic/react';
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { App } = Plugins;

const ionRouter = useIonRouter();

document.addEventListener('ionBackButton', (ev) => {
  ev.detail.register(-1, () => {
    if (!ionRouter.canGoBack()) {
      //Chame a mensagem de confirmação customizada aqui, se confirmar execute App.exitApp();
    }
  });
});
```

Vue:

```
import { useBackButton, useIonRouter } from '@ionic/vue';
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { App } = Plugins;

export default {
  setup() {
    const ionRouter = useIonRouter();
    useBackButton(-1, () => {
      if (!ionRouter.canGoBack()) {
      //Chame a mensagem de confirmação customizada aqui, se confirmar execute App.exitApp();
      }
    });
  }
}
```

JavaScript:

```
import { BackButtonEvent } from '@ionic/core';
import { Plugins } from '@capacitor/core';
const { App } = Plugins;

const routerEl = document.querySelector('ion-router');

document.addEventListener('ionBackButton', (ev: BackButtonEvent) => {
  ev.detail.register(-1, () => {
    const path = window.location.pathname;
    if (path === routerEl.root) {
      //Chame a mensagem de confirmação customizada aqui, se confirmar execute App.exitApp();
    }
  });
});
```

Então pode usar o ion-alert (é só uma sugestão, você pode fazer como desejar esse passo) para criar um modal de confirmação https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/alert, exemplo em Angular:

```
  async confirmarSairDoAplicativo() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Sair do aplicativo!',
      message: 'Deseja realmente fechar o aplicativo?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          role: 'cancel',
          cssClass: 'secondary',
          handler: (blah) => {
            console.log('Nada ocorre');
          }
        }, {
          text: 'Okay',
          cssClass: 'danger',
          handler: () => {
            App.exitApp();
          }
        }
      ]
    });

    await alert.present();
  }
```